# Updating database by decrements Library Book Stock

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I am trying to reduce the book availability by one for EACH book that is bought as part of a transaction - I have 50 books records in DB.

P.S. I know about SQL Injection - I will sort that out.

The code below shows the new transaction record being inserted in DB - What I would like to implement is that, when a new record is inserted in DB, the book that was bought is reduced by '1' availability.

```
private void btnPay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename= C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Library System Project.mdf ;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

        string Query = "insert into BookSale_Transactions (CustomerID, BookISBN, DateSold) values ('" + this.txtCustomerID.Text.Trim() + "','" + this.cbBookName.SelectedValue + "','" + this.msktxtDateSold.Text.Trim() + "');";

        SqlConnection DBCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand DBCommand = new SqlCommand(Query, DBCon);
        SqlDataReader DBReader;

        try
        {
            DBCon.Open();
            DBReader = DBCommand.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("New transaction record added to the system.", "Library System", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            DBCon.Close();

            this.txtCustomerID.ResetText();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more a SQL question rather than a c# question but you have 2 ways to go about this:

1. First would be to use a store procedure to make 2 transactions, 1 for the insert in the book sale transaction and another one to update the table where you hold the information about the book removing 1 from the count item. This one seems to be best and more secure due to being a store procedure
2. Second way, would be to have 2 querys, one for the insert, and one for the update, and execute the reader for both querys. This is less secure but it will get the job done from c#

Provided my answer, I strongly suggest you into looking into Store Procedures.

Edit: This is how you make a transaction

```
SqlTransaction tran;
    try
    {
            DBCon.Open();
            tran = DBCon.BeginTransaction();
            DBReader = DBCommand.ExecuteReader();
            DBReader2 = DbCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("New transaction record added to the system.", "Library System", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            tran.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Appreciate the feedback @nalnpir - This is not a major project, it is an academic one, so following the 2nd option should be ok. Having said that, do the 2 queries have to be below each other for this to work, or would the update need to be placed elsewhere, please?

Comment: You can do one below the other one without any trouble, but you should take into account that if the second fail you should revert the full commit, since you may be able to enter the sale transaction but not update the book row or vice versa, for whatever reason